# geom_text label with by the use of a numerical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to label text (it's a variable) using geom_text:

```
geom_text(aes(as.Date("2018-03-05"), -8), label = A_Statrd)
```

I get this error:

> Fehler: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (31): label

How can I treat a variable as a label?

Text works well. When I use quotation marks, he will write me the text into my graphic. But this is not what I want. I'd like to take a variable. The variable is numeric.

For any tips/advice I thank you very much.

Comment: could you show `A_Statrd`?

Comment: try to put the `label = A_Statrd` inside the `aes()` or try `annotate` which seems to be a better choice for your task

Answer (score 0):

`geom_text` is going to expect `label` as an aesthetic, so it expects it will be receiving a column of your dataframe---hence the error about the vector length.

Two options:

One: make a dummy dataframe with this label in it, something like

```
data.frame(x = as.Date("2018-03-05"), y = -8, label = A_Statrd)
```

and use that as the `data` parameter in your call to `geom_text`.

Or two: the better option, as suggested in one of the comments, is to use `annotate` instead of `geom_text`. This is the situation `annotate` was designed for, where you have a bit of text or other annotation that *isn't* mapped to your data, but is instead some static piece of information. Use something like

```
ggplot(...) + 
    annotate(geom = "text", x = as.Date("2018-03-05"), y = -8, label = A_Statrd)
```

This assumes that `A_Statrd` is a variable you have stored elsewhere---that's what it seems like from your question.